# not able to open chrome using selenium web driver. my code is as follows

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried the following code, but was unsuccessful. Please help me with it.

Code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver .chrome.driver","/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ccs_func_test_build/ccs-cpw-automation-framework/../Input_Files/chromedriver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.setBinary("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ccs_func_test_build/ccs-cpw-automation-framework/../Input_Files/chromedriver");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

There is a space in you code webdriver .chrome.driver should be webdriver.chrome.driver

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply.  it was a typo error.. even without space it is not working(actually in my code it is without space).

Comment: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ccs_func_test_build/ccs-cpw-automation-framework/../Input_Files ------ it is the path where i have my chrome.exe for windows and chrome binary file for linux(amd64). while running in windows same code works when I change the binary file. help me out to execute in linux.

Comment: i am getting the following error: The driver is not executable: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ccs_func_test_build/ccs-cpw-automation-framework/../Input_Files/chromedriver

Comment: there is no extension after chromedriver . is that the error ? in that case what should be the extension  for the linux ?

Comment: For getting the path of the project and avoiding all dots in the path use System.getProperties("user.dir"). This returns the path of the project and to this append the folder in which your chorme driver is present. Also the name of the drive should be chromedriver.exe and not just chromedriver

Comment: guys, you are wrong. The chromedriver for linux is actually really just `chromedriver` see the file you download for linux here: http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list the asker did not mention it in his original question but seems so that he is using linux...

Comment: i downloaded that chromedriver from the same link which you mentioned above. my linux server architecture is Linux(amd64), i downloaded the respective file and placed in the path mentioned above.

Comment: i am creating a automated test scripts using selenium web-driver. My test scripts are running very fine in firefox both in my local machine(windows 7) and in the server(Linux 64). same test scripts if i run in server on firefox they work fine, if i change the browser to chrome as mentioned in the above code it is failing. :(

Comment: Does it fail even in your local chrome? Or is it that it is failing only in server?

Comment: in my local chrome it is successful, but when i run it in local windows machine i have to give the binary for windows which is "chromedriver.exe" instead of "chromedriver" which is for linux(it is also there in the same directory). it is failing only in server

Answer (score 0):

According your comments:

1st: I do not like the two dots in the path. Please make sure there is whole path for linux machine, because `..` can be interpreted as "one directory up" in linux systems.

2nd: Make sure that the `chromedriver` file is made as executable. Screen from Ubuntu:
[image: chromedriver properties]
Please note that "allow executing file as program" is checked.

In command line it should be `chmod +x chromedriver` but please doublecheck that, I am linux newbie

Then it shoud work

Comment: actually that ".." works for me, i am appending the absolute path. how can i use that "chmod +x chromedriver" in my program ? basically i am trying to run tests in server where i can run only my program. please let me know how to do it using java ?? thank you..

Comment: please update your original question - what is the setup, what are you trying to do, what did you try so far. Because so far we are only guessing what you are trying to do...

Comment: i am creating a automated test scripts using selenium web-driver. My test scripts are running very fine in firefox both in my local machine(windows 7) and in the server(Linux 64). same test scripts if i run in server on firefox they works fine, if i change the browser to chrome as mentioned in the above code it is failing. :(